# Get region of bucket using AWSS3GetBucketLocationRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bolts-framework

I seem to have trouble understanding how to best deal with the **BFTask** (Bolts framework) return object for several AWS SDK iOS v2 methods. I am trying to get the name of the region my bucket resides in. Could anyone suggest how to do that given the **locationConstraint** information I am successfully receiving from the following code? Or is there a generic way to understand what the task.result object contains?

```
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
AWSS3 *myS3 = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:self.configurationS3];
AWSS3GetBucketLocationRequest *locReq = [AWSS3GetBucketLocationRequest new];
locReq.bucket=@"testAWS";

[[myS3 getBucketLocation:locReq] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if(task.error != nil){
        NSLog(@"%s Location not found: [%@]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, task.error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Location found: [%@] - %li", task.result, [task.result locationConstraint]);
    }
    return nil;  
}];
```

Also, if anyone has suggestions for tutorials/examples for best understanding BFTask that would be helpful. Thanks for your help. Cheers, Trond 
ps. I also asked this question on [AWS support site](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=156735&tstart=0).

Comment: I don't see where you've given us an example of the `locationConstraint` information that you are successfully getting.

Comment: My locationConstraint is always 0 just as Yosuke is saying in his answer. My worry was how to convert the numerical value to a string identifying the region. However, I agree I should have provided more info as you suggested stating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet to determine the bucket location:

```
AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
AWSS3GetBucketLocationRequest *getBucketLocationRequest = [AWSS3GetBucketLocationRequest new];
getBucketLocationRequest.bucket = testBucketNameGeneral;

[[s3 getBucketLocation:getBucketLocationRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if(task.error != nil){
        XCTAssertNil(task.error, @"The request failed. error: [%@]", task.error);
    }

    AWSS3GetBucketLocationOutput *getBucketLocationOutput = task.result;
    XCTAssertEqual(getBucketLocationOutput.locationConstraint, AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintBlank);
    switch (getBucketLocationOutput.locationConstraint) {
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintBlank:
            NSLog(@"Classic Region");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintEU:
            NSLog(@"EU");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintEUWest1:
            NSLog(@"eu-west-1");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintUSWest1:
            NSLog(@"us-west-1");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintUSWest2:
            NSLog(@"us-west-2");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintAPSoutheast1:
            NSLog(@"ap-southeast-1");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintAPSoutheast2:
            NSLog(@"ap-southeast-2");
            break;
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintAPNortheast1:
            NSLog(@"ap-northeast-1");
        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintSAEast1:
            NSLog(@"sa-east-1");
            break;

        case AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintUnknown:
        default:
            // Error
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

However, there is a bug in the SDK, and `getBucketLocationOutput.locationConstraint` is always `AWSS3BucketLocationConstraintUnknown`. We are working on the fix right now.

The [Bolts-iOS GitHub repo](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) has a pretty good instructions on how to use Bolts.

Hope this helps,

---

**Update**

The AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.0.4 has been released. The update fixes the issue, and now it returns the correct `locationConstraint`.